# MySQL - Search JSON data column

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, function

I have a MySQL database column that contains JSON array encoded strings. I would like to search the JSON array where the "Elapsed" value is greater than a particular number and return the corresponding TaskID value of the object the value was found. I have been attempting to use combinations of the JSON_SEARCH, JSON_CONTAINS, and JSON_EXTRACT functions but I am not getting the desired results.

```
[
    {
        "TaskID": "TAS00000012344", 
        "Elapsed": "25"
    },
    {
        "TaskID": "TAS00000012345",
        "Elapsed": "30"
    },
    {
        "TaskID": "TAS00000012346",
        "Elapsed": "35"
    },
    {
        "TaskID": "TAS00000012347",
        "Elapsed": "40"
    }
]
```

Referencing the JSON above, if I search for "Elapsed" > "30" then 2 records would return

1. `'TAS00000012346'`
2. `'TAS00000012347'`

I am using MySQL version 5.7.11 and new to querying json data. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Can you show your table structure? If I'm not mistaken you have to have your columns defined as actually JSON type or in order to use those functions you need at least to cast your varchar field to a json type, take a look here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-paths

Comment: _"I have a MySQL database column that contains JSON array encoded strings"_ Why?

Comment: The column that contains the JSON data is simply a 'text' datatype. The JSON functions do work regardless of the datatype. Probably not as well as they should/could though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With MySQL pre-8.0, there is no easy way to turn a JSON array to a recordset (ie, function `JSON_TABLE()` is not yet available).

So, one way or another, we need to manually iterate through the array to extract the relevant pieces of data (using `JSON_EXTRACT()`). Here is a solution that uses an inline query  to generate a list of numbers ; another classic approchach is to use a number tables.

Assuming a table called `mytable` with a column called `js` holding the JSON content:

```
SELECT 
    JSON_EXTRACT(js, CONCAT('$[', n.idx, '].TaskID')) TaskID,
    JSON_EXTRACT(js, CONCAT('$[', n.idx, '].Elapsed')) Elapsed
FROM mytable t
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 idx 
    UNION ALL SELECT 1 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3
) n
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(js, CONCAT('$[', n.idx, '].Elapsed')) * 1.0 > 30
```

NB: in the `WHERE` clause, the `* 1.0` operation is there to force the conversion to a number.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nxmtvRZxugdyHrKDiRQRBR/0)** with your sample data:

```
| TaskID         | Elapsed |
| -------------- | ------- |
| TAS00000012346 | 35      |
| TAS00000012347 | 40      |
```

Comment: GMB , thank you very much. It does indeed work. Can you explain what the "n.idx" does ?

Comment: @JNicolls: welcome! `n` is the alias for the subquery that produces the list of numbers, and `idx` is the column that contains the number itself. So `n.idx` produces `0`, then  `1`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes , you can definitely to it using JSON_EXTRACT() function in mysql.

lets take a table that contains JSON (table `client_services` here) :

```
+-----+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| id  | client_id | service_values                       |
+-----+-----------+------------+-------------------------+
| 100 |      1000 | { "quota": 1,"data_transfer":160000} |
| 101 |      1000 | { "quota": 2,"data_transfer":800000} |
| 102 |      1000 | { "quota": 3,"data_transfer":70000}  |
| 103 |      1001 | { "quota": 1,"data_transfer":97000}  |
| 104 |      1001 | { "quota": 2,"data_transfer":1760}   |
| 105 |      1002 | { "quota": 2,"data_transfer":1060}   |
+-----+-----------+--------------------------------------+
```

And now lets say we want client_id for all who have quota>1 , then use this query :

```
SELECT 
    id,client_id,
    JSON_EXTRACT(service_values, '$.quota') AS quota
FROM client_services
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(service_values, '$.quota') > 1;
```

And hence it will result into :

```
+-----+-----------+-------+
| id  | client_id | quota |
+-----+-----------+--------
| 101 |      1000 |     2 |
| 102 |      1000 |     3 |
| 104 |      1001 |     2 |
| 105 |      1002 |     2 |
+-----+-----------+-------+
```

hope this helps!