# How to search for specific data inside a JSON data at table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, phpmyadmin

I have a table named `carts` which has this structure:

```
1   crt_id Primary  bigint(20)      
2   crt_mbr_id      bigint(20)          
3   crt_session_id  varchar(128)    
4   crt_content     text    
5   crt_send_type   int(11)         
6   crt_completed   tinyint(1)          
7   created_at      timestamp           
8   updated_at      timestamp
```

And `crt_content` data goes like this:

`[{"id":"24","quantity":"1","price":3000,"discounted":3000,"coupon":0}]`

Now I need to search in `crt_content` for the number `24`. But I don't know what is the sql command for this.

So would you mind helping me out on how to search for specific data inside a JSON data which is stored at the table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - Search JSON data column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112450/mysql-search-json-data-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `JSON_EXTRACT` function like shown below in your where clause:

```
JSON_EXTRACT(crt_content, "$.id") = "24"
```

Though, I'd like to warn you, that I would not recommend this for a solution, containing a large amount of data. If you wish to read more about JSON search functions, take a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html).